# Tableau calculate percentage from a value in the table

Tags: tableau-api, percentage

I'm trying to calculate the percentage in Tableau from a value in a table.

For example. I have a table that contains the following

```
Name Value
a    10
b    20
c    30
Ref  100
```

How can I have the percentages calculated based on the Ref value like for example a/Ref

```
Name Value Percentage (x/Ref)
a    10    10%
b    20    20%
c    30    30%
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either

1. use tableaus built in functionality:

Right click the measure pill and select "quick table calculation -> Percentage of total"

2.Use calculated fields.

Create a calculated field(Analysis->Create Calculated Field) called reference. As the value enter the integer you want.

Create a second calculated field call it percentage. Here enter the mathematical formula to get a percentage using the reference calculated field as your total.

So something like:

```
[Value] / [refrence] *100
```

You don't need the reference calc field, you could just hard code the value into the calculation.

Drag the percentage calculated field into the row shelf.

Comment: Thanks lampbob. I managed to to it with your 1st point. I need to hide Ref    name. With the 2nd point, I see that I get the same results, but if I move the calculated field to the label I don't get the percentages. Also, I have to hide the Ref name.